# Replacing a section of the data in a cell for thousands of excel data

Tags: excel, vba

I have a large spreadsheet with column data like:

```
ABC:1:I.0
ABC:1:I.1 
ABC:1:I.2
ABC:1:I.3
ABC:2:I.0
ABC:2:I.1
ABC:2:I.2
ABC:2:I.3
ABC:3:I.0
ABC:3:I.2
ABC:3:I.3
ABC:4:I.0
ABC:4:I.1
ABC:4:I.2
ABC:4:I.3
ABC:5:I.0
ABC:5:I.1
ABC:5:I.2
ABC:5:I.3
ETC.
```

I need to replace the above with the following:

```
ABC:I.Data[1].0
ABC:I.Data[1].1
ABC:I.Data[1].2
ABC:I.Data[1].3
ABC:I.Data[2].0
ABC:I.Data[2].1
ABC:I.Data[2].2
ABC:I.Data[2].3
ABC:I.Data[3].0
ABC:I.Data[3].2
ABC:I.Data[3].3
ABC:I.Data[4].0
ABC:I.Data[4].1
ABC:I.Data[4].2
ABC:I.Data[4].3
ABC:I.Data[5].0
ABC:I.Data[5].1
ABC:I.Data[5].2
ABC:I.Data[5].3
ETC.
```

Here is a sample of the data, most of the data follows a similar format with the exception of the naming "ABC", which can vary in size, so it might be "ABCD" and also with the exception of the letter "I", it can be "O" as well. Also, some might be missing some values such as `ABC:3:I.1` which is missing from the data. I am not too familiar with excel formulas or VBA code. Does anyone know how to do this? I have no preference on which method it has to be done in as I don't mind learning some VBA code if someone provides me with a VBA solution.

I was thinking of using some sort of loop along with some conditional statements.

Thanks!

Comment: "All the numbers loop from 0 to 5" - I think you need to show a larger sample of your data, without any skipped rows. Is that last `.0` in the "to be" a typo ?

Comment: Alright, I fixed it, ignore what I said earlier about "All the numbers loop from 0 to 5".

Comment: VBA code? I don't have any yet, excel formulas are fine, I think it might be the better approach. I have been thinking of using append now. By extracting `ABC:` and then appending it to the values `1`, `I`, and `0` in `ABC:1:I:0`. Just not sure how to formulate this in excel.

Comment: This comment is a reply to the person who just posted a solution and then deleted it: Thanks, this works well, but is there a way for it to work for all cases, because the length may not always be `4`, there may be times it will be named `ABCD` or something else. Also, there will be cases where it will not be `I` but instead `O`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Please try](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256359/flag-try-this-code-answers-as-very-low-quality):

```
=LEFT(F11,FIND(":",F11))&MID(F11,FIND(":",F11,6)+1,1)&".Data["&MID(F11,FIND(":",F11,2)+1,1)&"]."&RIGHT(F11,1)
```

copied down to suit, assuming placed in Row11 and your data is in ColumnF starting in Row11.

---

Curiosities:

1. When this A was first posted it attempted to address only the tabulated example input and output. I temporarily deleted that version while addressing that what was in the table as `ABC` might at times be `ABCD` and that what was `I` might at times be `O`.
2. OP has posted an answer that I edited to make no visible change but which shows as the deletion of two characters. A copy of the OP’s formula exhibited a syntax error prior to my edit.
3. OP suggested an edit to my answer but this was rejected by the review process. As it happens, I think the edit suggestion was incorrect.
4. I have edited my answer again to include these ‘curiosities’ and to match the cell reference used by the OP in his answer.

Comment: Thanks! Your originally solution which was slightly off gave me the starting point for me to develop my own solution, here is what I have `=LEFT(F11,LEN(F11)-5)&MID(F11,LEN(F11)-2,2)&"Data["&MID(F11,LEN(F11)-4,1)&"]"&RIGHT(F11,2)` :D

Comment: I just tried your code and got a #VALUE! error, did it work when you tried it in your excel sheet? Haha, I will do that then, I did not know I cold answer my own question.

Comment: Just made a small edit to your solution. There was actually no #VALUE! issue, I think I just typed it in incorrectly but there was a problem with `MID(F8,FIND(":",F8,6)+1,1)`, it should be `MID(F8,FIND(":",F8,6)+3,1)` to get the proper value of `I` or `O`. It should work now :D.

Answer (score 1):

```
=LEFT(A1,SEARCH(":",A1)) & MID(A1, SEARCH(".",A1)-1, 2) &
  "Data[" & MID(A1,SEARCH(":",A1)+1,1) & "]" & RIGHT(A1,2)
```

Answer (score 1):

With the help of pnuts I was able to come up with my own solution:

```
=LEFT(F11,LEN(F11)-5)&MID(F11,LEN(F11)-2,2)&"Data["&MID(F11,LEN(F11)-4,1)&"]"&RIGHT(F11,2)
```

My solution works based on the fact that the length of the last six values in the string `ABC:1:I:0` will always be the same in size for all the data I have, hence you see `LEN(F11)-some number` in my code. The only part of the string that changes in size is the first part, in this case `ABC` which can also be `ABCDEF`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to use formulas rather than VBA, an easy option is to split the data into 4 columns, using the Text To Columns option - first split using the colon as a delimiter, then using a full-stop / period as a delimiter.

Once you have 4 columns of data (one for each block), you can use the Concatenate function to join them and add in the extra characters: `=CONCATENATE(A1,":",C1,".","Data[",B1,"].",D1)`

This should still work if you have extra / alternative characters (eg ABCD instead of ABC), as long as you have the same delimiters, but obviously you'd need to test to make sure.